# what does "class libraries on the classpath" mean?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

could anyone please clarify the meaning of **class libraries on the classpath** in the case of Tomcat in the following line:

Actually all classes used by the web-app(unless they're part of the **class libraries on the classpath**) must follow the same rules as servlet classes-inside WEB-INF/classes, in a directory structure matching the package (or in the appropriate package directories within a JAR inside WEB-INF/lib).

What do they mean with class libraries and classpath in the above paragraph?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like they're distinguishing between the .class files in your web app, packaged in a WAR file using the standard WEB-INF idiom, and those on the app server itself (e.g., in server/lib  and common/lib for Tomcat 5.x and lib for Tomcat 6.x).

The important thing for you to know is that Tomcat has a hierarchy of class loaders.  You need to understand how they work to use Tomcat effectively.

UPDATE: If understanding CLASSPATH is your issue, you need to know that anything WEB-INF/classes and in JARs under WEB-INF/lib in your deployment are in the CLASSPATH, along with JARs that are installed on your app server that all deployed applications share.  That's what I meant when I said common/lib and server/lib for Tomcat 5.x and lib for Tomcat 6.

I don't think I understand what your question is.  Do you not understand CLASSPATH?  The CLASSPATH is all the places that the JVM knows to look when it needs a .class file that hasn't been loaded yet.  That includes the JARs available to all applications deployed on Tomcat and WEB-INF/classes and WEB-INF/lib directories for your particular deployment.

Comment: Sir, do you mean with 'classpath' here - the path of the classes in Tomcat, and with class libraries - the classes store in the Tomcat. Sorry, if don't understand you correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The `classpath` is a list of locations where the JVM should look to find classes. By default, this has things like `rt.jar` and `vm.jar` on it which contain the classes like `java.lang.String`. You can append directories and jars to the classpath to allow the VM to find classes beyond those installed by default.

A `class library` is a collection of classes packaged to be used by applications. For all practical purposes, it is a jar with useful classes in it like `junit.jar`.

What the message is saying is: If you want to use a library class (like something from log4j), it needs to be on the classpath, in WEB-INF/classes or WEB-INF/lib.